# Avoiding Duplicate Records - SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have the data I need to create new records in a table.

However, at least some of the records I'll be inserting already exist (possibly all).

What is the proper statement to avoid duplicate records?

Comment: What if you tried? Would you learn from the docs if you read about the SELECT and Predicates on Join?

Comment: Look into `WHERE NOT EXISTS`...

Comment: The proper statement is MERGE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: I'm not sure I would have closed this as duplicate.  Another option for you to consider would be to add a unique constraint on the columns which define a pair of records as being "duplicate."  With such a constraint in place, any attempt to insert a duplicate would fail at the database level.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  "Where Not Exists" should take care of it and  sorry for the duplicate